# Compilation order and compilation dependencies

Tags: c, gcc

Suppose I have a C program separated into several smaller files and include each other as follows :

[image: Taken from http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node3.html]

Now I have the following queries as to what extent I am correct. Please correct me wherever I am wrong:

```
1. Which files have to recompiled after I make changes to process1.c?
```

main.c ?

```
2. Which files have to recompiled after I make changes to process1.h?
```

main.c and process1.c?

```
3. Which files have to recompiled after I make changes to list.h?
```

input.c and process2.c?

Comment: The file `output.c` cannot provide any useful services to the rest of the code because there is no header that declares the functions it provides to the other files.  So, there's a bug in the question description.  Either `output.c` should include `process1.h`, or there should be an `output.h` header that is included by `output.c` and one or more of the other source files.

Answer (score 3):

This is really easy.  If *X* gets changed, any .c file that includes *X* (or is *X*) needs to get recompiled.  The answers are:

1. process1.c
2. process1.c, main.c
3. process2.c, input.c

Answer (score 0):

I think the best answer to your question is to write a `Makefile` and then to check which files are compiled after changing one like your question.

Comment: Maybe you could add an example on how to do this such that it computes the dependencies.

Comment: No, this is a really basic question that one should understand before they attempt to create a Makefile.  You need to understand how to answer this question before you can know whether your Makefile is behaving correctly.

Comment: I'm agree with you and it's a basic which I understand. Maybe for someone which have some diffulcults to understand, it can be better to write a Makefile to understand how the files are compiled after a change.

Comment: The point is that the Makefile will not calculate the dependencies for you just out of the blue.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put:

> A file has to be recompiled if any of the files it depends on has been changed.

Note that this is recursive, so if any of the object files has changed because they have been recompiled, the program file (which normally depends on all object files) has to be re-built (i.e. linked, not compiled), too.

You might try [SCons](http://www.scons.org/) as an easier and more powerful alternative to good ol' make.